# Getting the pathname of a URL stored in a variable

Tags: jquery, pathname

I'm trying to get /blog in order to put in url_pathname.

```
var link = 'http://www.example.com/blog';
alert(url_pathname);
```

if the link was 'http://www.example.com/blog/post', url_pathname would be /blog/page

I tried the following without success.

```
var link = 'http://www.example.com/blog';
var url_pathname = link[0].pathname;
alert(url_pathname);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pathname` properties are only available on the `location` object and link elements. Assign the string to an anchor, and read the value from the parsed link, as follows:

```
var link = 'http://www.example.com/blog';
var a = document.createElement('a'); // Create a dummy <a> element
a.href = link;                       // Assign link, let the browser parse it
var url_pathname = a.pathname;
alert(url_pathname);
```

---

Explanation of your failed method:

- `link` is a string.
- When you use `link[0]`, you get the first character of the string, `h`.
- Then, you're trying to get the `pathname` property of it. This property is not defined on the string, hence you receive `undefined`.
  *(added this explanation to clarify why JavaScript didn't throw an error)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this, made it less verbose:

```
//var link = 'http://www.example.com/blog'; // try this
var link = "http://www.example.com/blog/post";
var i = link.indexOf('.com')​​​;//assuming ends in .com, find where it starts
alert(link.substring(i+4));//use +4 to skip .com
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c6MMz/

​